# Creating a reusable class in python

Tags: python, class, paramiko

I need to work with remote files transparently as if they were local files in some python code I'm writing, so I decided to use SFTP for this task.  The following code example works (it prints the first line of the remote file):

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='192.168.8.103', username='root', password='pyjamas')
sftp = client.open_sftp()
test = sftp.open('/var/log/example/ingest.log', mode='r', bufsize=1)
print test.readline()
```

I am going to be connecting to many files, so I decided to write a class that gives me an SFTPFile object.  Examine the following code:

```
import paramiko

class RemoteLog(object):
    """This class implements the remote log buffer."""

    def __init__(self, host, user='', pw='', log=''):
        """Initializes a connection to a remote log."""

        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=pw)
        sftp = client.open_sftp()
        self.log = sftp.open(log, mode='r', bufsize=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = RemoteLog(host='192.168.8.103', user='root', pw='pyjamas', log='/var/log/example/ingest.log')
    print test.log.readline()
```

Unfortunately readline() in this scenario returns nothing.  There are no errors or obvious explanations.

How should I replicate the functionality from my first code snippet into a reusable class?

Comment: Try holding a reference to sftp and client (`self.client = paramiko...` and `self.sftp = self.client.open_sftp()`).  My only guess is that when they go out of scope, they automatically clean up and close the connection.

Comment: if you add `print self.log.readline()` inside `__init__` do you get what you are looking for? @gfortune same idea :-)

Comment: @gfortune: that appears to have done it!  Did seem that they cleaned up the connection after losing scope, checking for the connection at the other end would have shown this.

Comment: @gfortune, as soon as I saw your comment I knew you were right. Add it as an answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't add an answer as I didn't know for sure. Glad to hear it worked. Added an answer with that info as well as some additional advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the sftp connection is closed when the variables go out of scope in `__init__`.  Storing a reference to those in the class fixes the problem.

```
def __init__(self, host, user='', pw='', log=''):
    """Initializes a connection to a remote log."""

    self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.client.load_system_host_keys()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=pw)
    self.sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
    self.log = self.sftp.open(log, mode='r', bufsize=1)
```

As an extra piece of advice, you might consider implementing the standard file object functions and hide the self.log reference behind your object.  Instead of `test.log.readline()`, you really should be able to use `test.readline()` as you are trying to wrap a file-like object (you should really implement a `close()` method as well).  There's a bit of work doing so, but it's a one-time effort and will make the code that uses this class a lot cleaner.